# Which grant type for oauth 2 token in java for single web application[BOT with email,OTP AND web application with username,password]

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have my web application where we are migrating to oauth2 protected API's from spring security.

For web application we used oauth2 (grant type password) implementation and it worked. (With username , password entered and oauth token issued)
But at the same time we have another part of application running which is BOT where we don't need username and password but we accept email address and otp and allow for next actions.Here facing issue how to generate auth token as user is not going to enter username and password.

Comment: if the user has to enter only his username, without the password - how do u secure this? how u make sure this is the right person?

Comment: Hi OhadR, we are verifying his email address in our DB, if it is valid we generate OTP and send to his email Id , if OTP is correct he is allowed in BOT application.[This bot application is for users who are not that frequent users of application so , probably they won't be remembering username and password details ]

Comment: try implementing multiple authentication providers as shown in this example. https://github.com/gdong42/spring-auth-example